# how to add options to inflect number-to-word?

Tags: python

I have a program which calculates the number of minutes of a person's age.  It works correctly.  However, I want to ask if I can print the first letter capitalized.

```py
from datetime import datetime, date
import sys
import inflect
inflector = inflect.engine()

def main():
    # heute = date.today()
    user = input('Date of birth: ')
    min_preter(user)


def min_preter(data):
     try:
        data != datetime.strptime(data, '%Y-%m-%d')

        # Get the y-m-d in current time
        today = date.today()

        # die y-m-d teilen
        year, month , day = data.split('-')
        # Convert to datetime
        data = date(year=int(year), month=int(month), day=int(day))

        # And valla
        end = (today - data).total_seconds() / 60

        # Convert to words
        words = inflector.number_to_words(end).replace('point zero','minutes').upper()
        return words
    except:
        sys.exit('Invalid date')
        # convert from string format to datetime format

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here is the output when I enter e.g `1999-01-01`:

```
twelve million, four hundred and fifty-seven thousand, four hundred and forty point zero
```

where I expected

```
Twelve million, four hundred and fifty-seven thousand, four hundred and forty minutes
```

first word 'Twelve'(first letter capitalize)

I don't know what this `point zero` is.  I just want the minutes at the end.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `string.capitalize()`. So you can do that:

```
return words.capitalize()
```

... and as for the "point zero", try converting the result to int before running your function, like

```
end = int((today - data).total_seconds() / 60)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `.upper()` by `capitalize()` in your code

An alternative to your replace would be to obtain the total number of minutes as an integer (point zero is because end is a float number) :

```
end = int((today - data).total_seconds() / 60)
```

In that case, your words variable would be :

```
words = inflector.number_to_words(end).capitalize() + " minutes"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.capitalize()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.capitalize) to capitalize the first word of the string.

**EXAMPLE:** `words.capitalize()`

```py
"twelve million, four hundred and fifty-seven thousand, four hundred and forty point zero".capitalize()
```

**OUTPUT**

```py
'Twelve million, four hundred and fifty-seven thousand, four hundred and forty point zero'
```

### Regarding *point zero*

- This particular code `end = (today - data).total_seconds() / 60` is giving output as `float` which is leading to `point zero` so instead of `division` use `floor division` i.e. `//` instead of `/` which will return integer and hence `point zero` will be gone or else convert `end` to `int`.
- Lastly add `minutes` string i.e. `end + ' minutes'` to final result.